# How to open GUI folder manager in Awesome WM?

Tags: 13.04, awesome

I have installed awesome several hours ago. I do not know how to open folders in GUI. How to open graphical folder manager in Awesome WM ?

I mean the default GUI folder in Awesome WM.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please reflect on why you need a graphical file manager in the first place.
If you still desire graphics install a file manager such as Nautilus or Thunar and run it as any other application on your system. With Awesome you can run executables from PATH with mod+r, look at the official documentation.

Comment: So clarify why the above is not an answer

Answer (score 0):

From the tag you specified - `13.04` I assume that you've installed awesome on Ubuntu.

For Ubuntu default file manager is nautilus, to run it press `mod4+r` and type `nautilus`, or run it from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

open a terminal and type *nautilus*(if you are using it)